# declaration of an array in a function call

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, declaration

I am having an array called AR whose number of values has got to be unidentified.

Is it allowed to write for the following function:

```
void manipulation(int AR[], int pos, int val)
{
....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's allowed. However, the function will not know how many elements the array contains. Also, AR will reference the same memory block as the value that you pass into the function. A copy will not be made. But if I interpret the name of your function correctly, this is your intention.

Comment: I shall include a hint to the function at the end introducing the number of arrays. Thank you @Oswald

Comment: int AR[] is allowed and perfectly OK. However, since AR is nothing else than a pointer, people often would write int *AR instead. That makes it clear just the pointer is being passed. You can still access members using AR[i], because you can do this with any pointer. The compiler will just multiply the index i with the size of one member, i.e. sizeof(int).

Comment: On the other hand, `int AR[]` makes it clear that `AR` is an array and not a pointer to a single int.

Comment: That's right, but the compiler won't check this; you may pass a pointer to a single int. Naming conventions may help here. I usually put 'arr' in front of the variable name, e.g. int *arrStuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array like that .
 And *(AR+i) to access your elements , that 'i' can be any value.